# Adding LSM ads in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to add lsm ads in chrome extension. I have added he code but the ads do not display. DO i need to set and kind of permission for being able to use JS?

Comment: I don't know anything about LSM ads specifically, but where are you trying to ad them? In the extension popup window? Or are you using the extension to try to inject them into pages the user browses?